# Warning from self-signed certificate using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, localhost, certificate, self-signed

I've generated a self-signed certificate using this command, with CN equal to "localhost":
**openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout private.pem**

(from https://gist.github.com/SeanPesce/af5f6b7665305b4c45941634ff725b7a)

When I execute the server with certificate and private key, and go to localhost, I get the warning from Firefox telling me that the certificate is self-signed, which was expected. But after importing the certificate as a CA, I get another warning:

*Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY

https://localhost/

The server uses a certificate with a basic constraints extension identifying it as a certificate authority. For a properly-issued certificate, this should not be the case.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
HTTP Public Key Pinning: false*

How do I solve the warning?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

I think you are using the Certificate Authority certificate instead of a normal certificate on your server. `CA_CERT_USED_AS_END_ENTITY` seems to say that. You should use a sub-certificate generated from the CA.

#### Create the certificate

I've had a very similar issue, and created a tool for automatizing the process and make it easier to create self-signed certificates that are valid:

- [Github / Self-Signed Certificates Generator](https://github.com/Vinalti/Self-Signed-Certificates-Generator)

The process is quite simple:

- Clone the repository
- Execute the script `generate_certificate.sh`
- Follow the flow (and read the README)

Don't forget to have the correct name in the certificate mapping to your website or service, you should use a file containing the config with `DNS:localhost` or `IP:"127.0.0.1` (you might have to include the port number).

#### Installing the certificate on the server

On the server, you need to use the `hostname.priv.key` for the key and the chain `hostname.chain.pem` for the public certificate.

You should not use the Root Certificate (CA), but a certificate generated from the CA.

#### Trust the certificate on the client

You only need to trust the Certificate Authority (CA). There is also a full explanation on how to get it trusted by the different devices on the [project page](https://github.com/Vinalti/Self-Signed-Certificates-Generator). On Firefox I think you can (and must? ) import the `CA.pem` directly in Firefox under the security settings, but importing it on the host might just work as well, you need to test.

On a lower level, Christian Lempa made a very useful [SSL Certificates Cheatsheet](https://github.com/ChristianLempa/cheat-sheets).

Let me know if my answer was helpful !